# Limit top speed of an object tracked by x and y when moving in a rotation-based direction

Tags: algorithm, game-physics, pseudocode

Let's imagine I have some character that can rotate in 360 degrees, and I am tracking its position as x and y.

I am using `sin` and `cos` to determine its movement:

```
x += speed * cos(rotation)
y += speed * sin(rotation)
```

This works fine, but I figure I want an acceleration based system instead. So rather than increasing speed, I increase acceleration which then increases speed:

```
x_velocity += speed * cos(rotation)
y_velocity += speed * sin(rotation)
x += x_velocity
y += y_velocity
```

However, I don't want this character to be able to accelerate indefinitely and therefore I want to limit its top speed. Now, I could do this:

```
if x_velocity > maxspeed then x_velocity = maxspeed
if y_velocity > maxspeed then y_velocity = maxspeed
```

but this is imperfect, as it means you can travel 44% faster if you move at a perfect diagonal than if you travel in a cardinal direction.

So I use the pythagorean theorem, but I immediately run into a problem.

```
if sqrt(x_velocity^2 + y_velocity^2) > maxspeed then ???
```

Is there a solution? I cannot simply define it equal to `maxspeed` like before, but I also cannot completely allocate all the velocity to one axis, since that would change the direction. How do I determine the velocity to limit it at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use overall velocity

```
 velocity = Min(max_velocity, velocity + speed) //really acceleration instead of speed
 x_velocity  = velocity * cos(rotation)
 y_velocity  = velocity * sin(rotation)
 x += x_velocity
 y += y_velocity
```

If you have to maintain x_velocity and y_velocity (by some strange reason), then you can limit overall velocity through it's components with direction preserving:

```
... update x_velocity, y_velocity
vel = sqrt(x_velocity^2 + y_velocity^2) 
if vel > max_velocity then
    x_velocity = x_velocity * max_velocity / vel
    y_velocity = y_velocity * max_velocity / vel
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement this. I need to maintain x and y velocity because otherwise if the character changes direction he will instantly move toward the new direction at the same speed he moves towards the previous direction, which should not happen.

Comment: It is worth to maintain separate velocity components, if you have force components in X- and Y- directions (like gravity in Y etc).

Answer (score 0):

### DRAG

You want to add drag (friction) that will set a max speed (like freefall drag creates a terminal velocity)

To define movement

```
acceleration = 2.0; // the constant acceleration applied     
vx = 0.0;           // velocity x
vy = 0.0;           // velocity y
x = 0.0;            // current position
y = 0.0;
direction = 0.0;    // direction of acceleration
drag = 0.01;        // drag as a fraction of speed
```

To apply acceleration

```
vx += cos(direction) * acceleration ;
vy += sin(direction) * acceleration ;
```

To apply drag

```
vx *= 1 - drag;
vy *= 1 - drag;
```

To get current speed

```
speed = sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
```

#### Calculate drag for max speed.

If you want to set the max speed in terms of drag.

```
maxSpeed = 100.0;
drag = accel / (maxSpeed + accel);
```

The just apply acceleration and drag (in that order) to the velocity and the character will never go above `maxSpeed`

An important note is that if the character changes direction when near maxSpeed there will be a drop in speed related to the amount of change in velocity. EG if direction changes 180 then the character will slow down at an amount equal to `accel + speed * drag` (drag is helping the deacceleration)  until the velocity starts to increase again at which point acceleration is `accel - speed * drag`

The final solution to set a max speed in terms of drag,

```
acceleration = 2.0; // the constant acceleration applied     
vx = 0.0;           // velocity x
vy = 0.0;           // velocity y
x = 0.0;            // current position
y = 0.0;
direction = 0.0;    // direction of acceleration
maxSpeed = 100.0;
// set drag to give a maxSpeed 
drag = acceleration / (maxSpeed + acceleration);
```

The apply acceleration and drag as follows

```
vx += cos(direction) * acceleration ;
vy += sin(direction) * acceleration ;
vx *= 1 - drag;
vy *= 1 - drag;
x += vx;
y += vy;
```

Speed will never go over maxSpeed. But also speed will never reach max speed, it will just keep on getting closer, but never quite getting there, though we are talking insignificant fractions of a unit 0.00000000001 pixels per frame

Comment: while I've already implemented the other answer, this seems a useful technique and will probably be helpful in the future :) so thanks anyway